# Why static final variable use static method initialization need synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

In Jetty source code, the `jetty-xml` module, `XmlConfiguration` has the following code:

```
java private static final XmlParser __parser = initParser();

private synchronized static XmlParser initParser() {
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
URL config60 = Loader.getResource(XmlConfiguration.class, "org/eclipse/jetty/xml/configure_6_0.dtd");
URL config76 = Loader.getResource(XmlConfiguration.class, "org/eclipse/jetty/xml/configure_7_6.dtd");
URL config90 = Loader.getResource(XmlConfiguration.class, "org/eclipse/jetty/xml/configure_9_0.dtd");

parser.redirectEntity("configure.dtd", config90);
parser.redirectEntity("configure_1_0.dtd", config60);
parser.redirectEntity("configure_1_1.dtd", config60);

...

return parser;
```

the `__parser` variable use the static method `initParser()` initialization.the `__parser` should be thread-safe,only load once by the classloader, why the `initParser()` need to use `synchronized`? Whether excess?

Further explanations：I debug the Jetty source code, from the `jetty-start` module, then invoke the `jetty-xml` module.

Comment: Is there anything else synchronizing on `XmlConfiguration.class`?

Comment: Atomicity quite possibly?

Comment: Maybe a look into the commit which introduces that `synchronize` might give an insight.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reply to everyone, maybe I have not 50 reputation.Here, I add some content.I debug the Jetty Source Code, from the `jetty-start` module, then invoke the `jetty-xml` module, eg, invoke the `XmlConfiguration#main()` method.In `XmlConfiguration` class, in the `XmlConfiguration` constructor, synchronized on `__parser`,eg. `synchronized (__parser) { ... }`, the source code can be fount on github, https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-xml/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/xml/XmlConfiguration.java.

Comment: `synchronized(__parser)` is a different monitor. The `git blame` also doesn't give an insight. For me it's a mystery. But I'm curious as well.

Comment: Yes,at last for now, I can't understand.I puzzled,(´･_･`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it needs to be synchronized at all.

The Java Language Specification guarantees that Java class initialization (i.e. the initialization of the classes `static`s, etcetera) is performed within a lock to prevent race conditions.  This applies whether the class is loaded once, or many times (i.e. by different class loaders).

I suspect that the author of this code was simply not aware of how the JVM handles this, and is taking unnecessary precautions.

(On the other hand, these "belt and braces" precautions are harmless, and the performance impact is trivial: probably unmeasurable.)

---

For the record, the procedure for class initialization is specified in the JLS in [Section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Comment: Yes,I agree.I had submit a bug to jetty, asked why.Take a look at how they reply.

Comment: @ykgarfield - I predict they will close it with status "won't fix" or similar.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it!

Comment: ha ha,I receive the autor reply, the `synchronized` is not necessary,They will fixed it.Anyhow, Thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that there is at most one class loader then there is no need for synchronization. The static initialization code is run once per class loader.

From what i can see in the Jetty WebAppContext only one class loader can be set in configuration.

Comment: Anyhow, Thanks, the author will fix it.The `synchronized` is not necessary